# Clone a repo with Slash in Password

Tags: git, passwords, clone

Cloning a repo can be done with

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

However, when the password contains a forward slash, this doesn't work. Error is:

```
error: Couldn't resolve host 'klaus777:password' while accessing 
https://klaus777:password/.@bitbucket.org/romeo/server-code.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

If I URL Encode the Slash, I get the following error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing 
https://klaus777:password%2F%2E@bitbucket.org/romeo/server-code.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Hence, the question: How do you deal with forward slash in password?

PS. If I remove password from URL and provide it when prompted, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

A [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for forward slash should be `%2F` alone, check if you need to encode the '`.`' (`%2E`) that you seem to *also* have in your password.

```
https://klaus777:password%2F.@bitbucket.org/romeo/server-code.git
```

That doesn't seem to work for GitHub though: the [OP Klaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202859/klaus) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718519/clone-a-repo-with-slash-in-password/24719496?noredirect=1#comment38367040_24719496):

> I changed the password.

Comment: Unfortunately, encoding only the forward slash does not work either.

Comment: @Klaus no need to encode the '.' (unreserved character). But for testing, can you check, for the '/', if this would work better? `%252F` or `%25252F`

Comment: @Klaus and make sure you didn't activated the 2FA (2 Form Authentication) on GitHub for your account, because then you would have to generate a token as a password, not use your regular account password.

Comment: I gave up. I changed the password. Unfortunately, these suggestions did not work either.

Comment: @Klaus Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.