# IntelliJ and AndroidStudio - connect to Gitlab.com respository

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, gitlab, ssh-keys

Via Git UI and Turtoise UI I updated the local and remote GIT repositories. 
I would like to interact with the gitlab.com repositories in Android Studio and IntelliJ. I keep on getting 401 or read errors.

In IntelliJ I tried to connect to the remote repository via VCS > GIT > Remotes and added the gitlab.com SSH entry. 
Also in Android Studio I could not connect to the remote repository.

**SOLUTION**: thanks to VonC. The SSH keys I registered at Gitlab.com were in my c:\users\myusername\.ssh folder. Via the Turtoise and GIT UI I could refer directly to these files.

Both the Android Studio and IJ IDE's use the %HOME% folder to find the SSH keys. This folder may refer tot the System's SSH folder. Because no SSH keys were available in that folder, I kept on getting connection errors.

The solution was in creating a command (.bat) file that does the following for IntelliJ:

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
c:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.1\bin"
idea.exe
```

And for AS:

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
c:
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\bin
studio64.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's be clear: if you are using https url, and your username/password GitLab.com account, your ssh keys have **nothing** to do with your connection attempt: those ssh keys (puttygen or not) will be ignored.

For https, you need your GitLab account credentials, and if your GitLab password has a special character in it, it needs to be [percent encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719496/6309) ([like a `@`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195690/6309)).

See also "[Handling Passwords for Git Remote Repositories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/handling-passwords-for-git-remote-repositories.html)" (again, nothing to do with ssh).

If you select "Clone git repositories using ssh" (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066442/6309)), then, even if Git does not find your ssh keys (or [if your public key is not properly registered in your GitLab account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html)), ssh will be able to fallback to the username/password authentication scheme.

---

To use ssh urls in AS (Andoird Studio):

- make sure to launch AS in a `CMD` session when `HOME` (type `set HOME`) is set to `%USERPROFILE%`,
- make sure to have generated openssh keys, as [described by GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair) and registered to your GitLAb profile, again as [described by GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html).
  You must see in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` (or `%HOME%\.ssh`) the files `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. No `ppk` puttygen keys required.

The OP adds:

> Ah, the `%HOME%` and `%USERPROFILE%` pointed to different locations. I set the `id_rsa` at `%USERPROFILE%` and `%HOME%` points to the system folder. So, using the `id_rsa.pub` from the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config \systemprofile` should also sufficie?

Actually, if HOME points to the system folder, it means AS is running with the system account, or Git was installed for the system account.
Don't: `HOME` should refers to `%USERPROFILE%`, and make sure `AS` is launched with your account.
The OP notes:

> `HOME=%USERPROFILE%` solution also works perfectly for IntelliJ, so it is not only for Android Studio.

Comment: For IntelliJ: I created local files, staged and committed them locally. Then via  VCS > Git > remote > I added the Https string. Then I pushed the content and it worked fine. QUESTION: where does IntelliJ store the username password for using this Giblab.com private repository?

Comment: For Android Studio: I could clone a project via New > Project from VCS > Git > using the Https gitlab.com string. Worked. What if I have a local repository, how can I store that in the remote repository for the first time? In AS I don't have a 'remotes' option.

Comment: @tjm1706 for your first question, Git for Windows comes with a native integration with the [Windows Credential Store](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) (`git config --global credential.helper manager`)

Comment: @tjm1706 you always can fallback to the command line, go to your local repo and add a remote that way: `git remote add origin /url/of/remote/repo`

Comment: AndroidStudio ... I have already aligned the local and remote repo's outside of AS. How can I now start in AS with the remote repo?

Comment: @tjm1706 check if pull/push options are active in AS: that would mean AS recognize your remote repo setting and can pull from or push to it from your local repo.

Comment: @tjm1706 do you have an error message? In command line, what is the output of `git status` and `git remote -v`?

Comment: Everything works fine from (separate) Git UI and Turtoise UI.
[1] git status = nothing open. [2] $ git remote -v
origin4 git@gitlab.com:johan974/GMS.git (fetch)
origin4 git@gitlab.com:johan974/GMS.git (push).

Comment: What error message do you have when trying the pull from AS? Does the push work?

Comment: The error message (screenshot) I have put at the bottom of the issue description. A pull via Turtoise works great. Does this have to do with SSH settings? In Turtoise I have full control of the C:\users\myname\.ssh\* files.

Comment: Yes, ssh could be the issue. An https url should work better. Or at least, try and launch AS from a CMD session where you have set HOME to ℅USERPROFILE℅ first.

Comment: When I type "set" I see that ℅USERPROFILE℅  points to c:\users\myname. Then I go to the AS bin folder. Type studio64.exe ... same result. When I clone via the http: string of gitlab.com I get a decent clone and can work with it.

Comment: Yes, you net to type `set HOME=℅USERPROFILE℅` first, before launching AS.

Comment: It was already set. So ℅USERPROFILE℅ pointed to  c:\users\myname. That's correct? By the way ... thank you very much for helping. The +50 will be yours unless there is an even better answer.

Comment: Yes, as long as your private public ssh keys are in ℅USERPROFILE℅\.ssh, named id_rsa, and id_rsa.pub, and your public key is registered to your gitlab profile.

Comment: I have a PUTTYGEN key in the folder as well. It is called id_dsa.ppk and is in the PUTTYGEN format. I checked, no difference.

Comment: No, you need openssh keys, without passphrase, and you need to copy the content of the public key to your gitlab profile

Comment: @tjm1706 I have included those last comments/recommendations in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated! Ah, the %HOME% and %USERPROFILE% pointed to different locations. I set the id_rsa at %USERPROFILE% and %HOME% points to the system folder. So, using the id_rsa.pub from the C:\WINDOWS\system32\config \systemprofile should also sufficie? The answer will help otheres as well, I think.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Thanks a lot, I will +50!

Comment: The HOME=%USERPROFILE% solution also works perfectly for IntelliJ. You could update that in your solution, so not only for Android Studio. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistaken GitHub supportwith GitLab projects plugin and trying to authenticate to GitHub using GitLab credentials. Search for GitLab plugin, install `gitlab projects`:
[image]

and configure it using GitLab URL and [API Key](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens) that you can find in your account settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For Android Studio, there is no 'gitlab' plugin. For IntelliJ there is only the "gitlab integration" plug-in. Should I use that one?

Comment: @tjm1706 I'm using Android Studio on the screenshots. Click on Plugins -> Browse Repository -> search for GitLab. I added another screenshot. in my answer.

Comment: Working with the API key ... is that done via the Project > settings > Deploy keys? Which one to use? What is the advantage of using API keys over the SSH keys or username/password?

Comment: API key is used to manage gitlab projects, ssh key to push code changes.

Comment: Please elaborate. And ... is the API key from gitlab.com found via  Project > settings > Deploy keys?

Comment: sshkey is used to security transfer source code between git repositories. api key is gitlab specific to manage your account.

Comment: That helped. Thank you +1

Comment: unable to find the api key in gitlab