# How can I git clone over https with a personal access token containing '/'?

Tags: git, bitbucket, access-token, git-clone

I am trying to clone a repository from Bitbucket using a personal access token:

```sh
$ git clone https://{user}:{token}@bitbucket.repo/myrepo.git
```

Bitbucket just created four times in a row an access token containing a forward slash (`/`). Using such a token with `git clone` produces the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://{user}:{token}@bitbucket.repo/myrepo.git': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

The fifth token (without a `/`) worked. So, how can I `git clone` over https with a personal access token containing `/`?

Comment: Maybe you could try url-encoding it, ie. replace `/` with `%2F`

Comment: works. sometimes the obvious solution is so close.

Comment: thank you @ThorAndreasRognan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone a repo with Slash in Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718519/clone-a-repo-with-slash-in-password)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+slash+url+encoding

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace all `/` with their url-encoded representation `%2F`.

Answer (score 9):

When you generate token from git, it is more likely to generate special characters in the access token. While you pass these tokens as is with the reserved special characters, you will end up with an error. To overcome that you need to replace the special characters with the corresponding characters.

In your case, you need to replace / with %2F.

```
!   #   $    &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]
%21 %23 %24 %26 %27 %28 %29 %2A %2B %2C %2F %3A %3B %3D %3F %40 %5B %5D
```

Ref: https://fabianlee.org/2016/09/07/git-calling-git-clone-using-password-with-special-character/